# Storing classes in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to have an array with list of my classes in order to allocaing them by index. The first I made is array with simple `NSStrings` with handy-typed names of classes. then, I just did the following:

```
id classAllocator = NSClassFromString([namesArray objectAtIndex:index]);
id classEntranse = [[classAllocator alloc] init];
```

But this system is very ustable in case of refactoring. I tried to do following:

```
@class myClass;
@class enotherClass;
classesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [myClass class], [enotherClass class], nil];
id classEntranse = [[[classesArray objectAtIndex:index] alloc] init];
```

But now, I,m getting warning "Reciver 'myClass' is a forward class and @interface May not Exist".
**I can not #import my classes**: that will by a cycle importing.

How can I dynamically store classes or there names in NSArray?

Comment: Why are you creating an array of `Class` objects?  We can give you better advice if you explain.

Comment: I'm getting in object ID fron server, and must to init an object with this ID. So, i'm getting it from array and allocating it.

Comment: You shouldn't #import .m files, so you should be fine. Use `@class ClassName` in your header files, then use `#import ClassName.h` in your implementation files. No more circular imports.

Comment: thanks in advice, I'l try it. It's quite a lot of code to refactor, so I need some time...

Comment: That works perfect. Could you post this as an answer, please?